# CA SCM Harvest Workbench E0306003e: Could not connect to Broker

Tags: version-control, harvest-scm

In CA SCM Harvest Workbench, Version 12. 1..1.141 We face below error while check our or promoted. Not always but frequently. What should be done to overcome this issue? I tried to reinstall PEC in user matching, but it didn't fix it. Any solutions?

```
E0306003e: Could not connect to Broker: /pt_HBroker://r62dp10/0/haprd5 (Error Code = -307)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Error Code = -307` usually means that your SCM client cannot connect to your server. Look for network connectivity issues, e.g. try `ping`ing server machine from client machine, try connecting to server:port via `telnet`. If you are an SCM administrator, ensure `bkrd` and `rtserver` are up and running. Otherwise, ask them.

If this happens just occasionally and stops happening by itself, there is probably some kind of problem in your network infrastructure, be it micro-cuts, noise, irregular latency...